# How to generalize a function to accept file path or file contents as string?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm writing a file parser that parses ".toml" files (using the [toml-rs](https://crates.io/crates/toml) crate) into Rust data types. Right now my function accepts `PathBuf` for the file path. I want to make it generic so that it can accept any type of source that contains TOML:

1. File paths, `PathBuf` or `Path`.
2. String that has toml data in it.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. Is `"data/config.toml"` a path or the contents? You can figure it out, but how would the compiler? it's a string

Comment: I'd agree with @kmdreko, "convenient confusion" is common in dynamically typed languages (e.g. a function which can take a path, file object, url, or content buffer) but the impliciteness and confusion would generally be frowned upon in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not going to be a good generic trait that's implement by both String and PathBuf they are too different. One is the content and one is a path to the content.

You could have two entry point functions one accepting a path/buf and one accepting a string (that then call the same helper)

```rust
pub fn parse_from_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Toml {
    let content = std::fs::read_to_string(path);
    parse(content)
}
pub fn parse(content: String) -> Toml {
    todo!();
}
```

Or you could use an enum like this:

```rust
enum ParseContent {
    PathBuf(PathBuf),
    Path(Path),
    Content(String)
}

pub fn parse(source: ParseContent) -> Toml { todo!() }
```

I prefer the first.

Comment: "There's not going to be a good generic trait that's implement by both String and PathBuf they are too different. " `AsRef` kinda does since there's an `AsRef<Path> for str`. Probably more to the point is there's no generic trait which would provide for both path *and content*: the AsRef case will treat the string as a path.